# open with explorer IE sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, open-with-explorer

hello I am facing this issue after I open with Explorer, any advice

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps to troubleshooting your issue:

1.Go to IE browser settings -> Internal options -> Security -> open each custom level of Internet、Local Intranet、Trusted sites -> User Authentication -> Automatic logon with current user name and password. Restart the IE browser, click open with explorer again.

2.Delete Internet Explorer cache. Go to IE browser settings -> Safety -> Delete browsing history -> Select Temporary Internet files, Cookies and website data and History from the menu -> Click the Delete button to delete the cache.

3.Go to services.msc, check the status of WebClient service.

4.Install the latest windows update.

5.For Internet Explorer 10 with Windows 7 or Windows 8, install the hotfix to resolve this problem.

References:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/912152/you-cannot-access-a-webdav-web-folder-from-a-windows-based-client-comp

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/troubleshoot-issues-using-open-with-explorer#for-internet-explorer-10-with-windows-7-or-windows-8-install-the-hotfix-to-resolve-this-problem

Comment: followed, but the same issue  exist

Answer (score 1):

Did you try what the error message suggested?
"add the web site to your trusted sites list"
This is a setting in IE.

Also, on your desktop, make sure the WebClient service is installed and running.

[image]

Comment: its already running but it still the same issue